# JavaFX - Add new PieChart.Data to existing Pie Chart

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I am curious how to add something to an already existing PieChart in JavaFx(i think im using 2.2.25, but i could update if it helps and if there is a newer version).

For instance:

```
ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new PieChart.Data("HD 7990", 65), new PieChart.Data("GTX 690", 35));
```

Now i want to 'append' another 'piece' to the cake, how to do that?
(btw i am using FXML from Scene Builder)

(Already tried this but it did not work(shortened version):

```
oldchart = pieChartData.getData();
ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(oldchart, new PieChart.Data("GTX 690", 35));
```

)

Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
pieChartData.add(new PieChart.Data("GTX 690", 35));
```

To remove last added one

```
pieChartData.remove(pieChartData.size() - 1);
```

To clear all 'pieces'

```
pieChartData.clear();
```

Since ,as you noticed, pieChartData is not an `java.util.ArrayList` but an `javafx.collections.ObservableList`, any changes made to pieChartData collection list will be reflected to the PieChart.

Comment: Thank you so much! (Somehow i didn't see it in the documentation D:)

Comment: Can i also somehow filter out one 'piece' by name?

Comment: @intlawlisover9000, read the documentation of ObservableList.get(Object item). Additionally, describe the filtering more comprehensively in new question.